# Did I answer these vector-related questions about this diagram correctly?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

In the diagram below, ABCDEF is a regular hexagon. MN is the perpendicular bisector of AB. O is the center of the hexagon.
$\vec{FA} = u$ and $\vec{FO}  = v$.

[image]

I was given these questions:

Write the following vectors in terms of u and v:

a) $\vec{FB}$

b)$\vec{BE}$

c)$\vec{AM}$

d)$\vec{MC}$

Give an example of a vector that is equal to:

e)$2u$

f)$u − v$

These were my answers:

a)$u + v$

b)$-2u$

c)$\frac 1 2$v

d)$\frac 3 2$v - u

e)$\vec{EB}$

f)$\vec{OA}$

Comment: All perfect. Nice!

Comment: Wait, it appears to me that $M$ and $N$ are on the respective arcs instead of chords...

Comment: What do you mean, peterwhy? In the task MN is stated to be the perpendicular bisector of AB.

Comment: Yes, $MN$ is the perpendicular bisector, but the task does not state that $M$ is on $AB$. And what I saw from the graph is that $M$ is on the circle instead of chord $AB$.

Comment: I think @peterwhy is right: if the drawing is accurate, $\;M\,,\,N\;$ are **not** on the hexagon but on the circumcircle! Then by no means $\;AM=\frac12v\;$ , for example...but I think the drawing is not accurate, otherwise no simple answer exists for anything related with $\;M,N\;$ ...

Comment: The drawing may not be accurate, but that's probably by they took the trouble to explicitly state that it was a regular hexagon and that $MN$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. This is a screenshot directly from the assignment text online: http://puu.sh/68tFj.png. In other words, even if it doesn't actually do so, that line is supposed to cross $AB$ exactly on the middle, and I am to answer as if it does.

Comment: Then it seems to be out of doubt: $\;M,N\;$ are not on the hexagon and thus things are waaaaay messier than it appeared at the beginning.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that, this is the first unit of a Canadian grade 12 math course. I'm very sure $M$ and $N$ are supposed to be points on the hexagon, I don't think they'd include a task that's beyond the scope of the unit (which so far has only covered vector addition and subtraction and basic plane figures).

Comment: See the mark between $A$ and $F$? To me that mark is midway on arc $MF$, and is probably hinting something. Also, the circle serves nothing extra if $M$ and $N$ are on the hexagon; why is the circle even there?

Comment: But there's no feasible way to represent $AM$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ if $M$ is not a point on the hexagon. Again, we're speaking high school math here.

Comment: Not sure what is in Canadian high school courses, but I imagine you have to find vector $\vec{OM}$ (my $M$) by scaling up $\vec{OM'}$ (your $M$). And this involves a factor of $\sin 60^\circ$.

Comment: Can this be represented in terms of $u$ and $v$ though? Neither of them have the angle of $OM$.

Comment: $\vec{OM}$ has the direction (but not magnitude) of $u-\frac12v$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these answers appear correct.